# Oracle telnet localhost 1521 connect failed

Tags: telnet, oracle-11g

Our service provider installed Oracle 11G on our Windows 2008 R2 server on vmware.

But we can not connect from another client on port 1521. And we can not also telnet localhost 1521 port on server.

We closed windows firewall and there is no antivirus software on server. We tried following telnet commands on server but none of them worked.

```
telnet localhost 1521
telnet 192.168.1.210 1521
telnet 127.0.0.1 1521

When we check with netstat -a we see following lines:

TCP    192.168.1.210:1521     FUWEB:0                LISTENING
TCP    192.168.1.210:1521     FUWEB:49193            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.1.210:1521     FUWEB:49227            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.1.210:1521     FUWEB:58399            ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.1.210:1521     FUWEB:58402            ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1521         FUWEB:58401            ESTABLISHED
TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           FUWEB:0                LISTENING
```